# Name of a manga in which the protagonist was at a supermarket and got transported to a deserted island and decided to revitalize the region

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I wish I could provide more details, but that's all I remember so far.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  How was he transported?  How do you revitalize a desert island?

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is *Seirei-tachi no Rakuen to Risou no Isekai Seikatsu*

The first chapter starts off with the main character shopping at a supermarket, leaving the building and appearing in a wasteland. He finds a small spirit who tells him that the area is called the land of the dead. After talking with a larger spirit, he finds out the area used to be a vibrant area, but has become an inhospitable wasteland. He then decides to attempt to revitalize the area. He does this by forming contracts with small spirits and slowly start growing things.